# Algorithm to find a frontline between enemy and friendly bases?

Tags: algorithm

Please look at this picture first: [image: Picture of battlefield]

As you can see, blue and red both have a line showing the frontline bases.

Let's assume two players start playing against eachother.

One placing a base at the far left, the other at the far right.

The players continue by expanding and gaining territory.

After a while, the two sides will meet and battle will start.

Question is, in a randomly ordered list of base positions how would one find the two lines that are drawn in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the distance between enemy bases, where the distance is shorter is the frontline.

Example:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 aa A   B bbb
1 aA      B bb
2 A        B b
3 aA       B b
4 aaaA      Bb
5 aaaA       B
6 aaaA       B
```

If you substract the X positions of the enemy bases in the same row, the ones with the less distance between them are the front lines, B.x - A.x will give you a smaller number that b.x - a.x. Then you can check which ones were the ones that gave you the smaller distance for each row.

Unless I'm getting your question wrong.

Comment: Good idea, however the location of the bases do not follow a specific grid system which means that A might have more frontline bases than B or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

**area**

- many games do not draw territory border by polylines
- instead they draw a disc with constant radius (or dependent on base strength) at every base position
- if the radius is set big enough then these discs/circles will overlap
- and create seamless area of single color representing controlled territory
- it is easy but inaccurate

**perimeter polyline**

1. first cluster all bases and create lists of bases close together

   - this can be done by grouping bases with `distance <= treshold`
2. process each group
3. find the outer most bases of group

   - something like perimeter points
   - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214) may help with it
   - also it contains inverse problem of yours which can solve the whole thing [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22295680/2521214)
4. now find the perimeter closed loop of area

   - the algorithm for that is also in the link above
   - when done then use this list of points as BEZIER cubics poly-curve control points
   - if borderline too close to the bases then enlarge the points
   - first compute avg point `ap` of group
   - then any point `p` is computed `p=((p-ap)*scale)+ap`
   - it is not exact but for your purposes it is enough
   - if you want something better then
   - `p=p-ap`
   - `l=|p|`
   - `p=ap+(p*(l+dl)/l)`
   - where dl is the step at which your border is enlarged
   - and if you want the accurate thing then you have to compute polygon enlargement
   - which is not easy task
5. handle edge cases

   - for singular base groups draw circle around
   - this approach has problem in close proximity of bases
   - one solution is not to count bases too close to any enemy base

**per pixel borders**

- you can process the map image by pixels
- something like this: (beware this is not tested)

  1. per each pixel
  2. compute the min distance to any player bases

     - remember two closest distances of different players
     - `distance0` is closest
     - `distance1` is second closest (but base owns another player)
  3. select territory ownership

     - the player which has closest base own this
     - if the `distance0 > treshold` then this area is uncontrolled
     - in that case stop processing this pixel
     - if `((distance0 >= d-w)&&(distance0 <= d+w)&&(distance1>d+w+s))` then set pixel color to border polyline color
     - `d` is border line distance from base
     - `w` is half-size of borderline thickness
     - `s` is min distance between close front lines
  4. edge case

     - previous step ignore border points that are closer to bases (close enemy bases)
     - to add them just add
     - if `((distance0<d)&&(|distance0-distance1|<=s+w)&&(|distance0-distance1|>=s-w))` then set pixel color to  player ownership
     - also this will fail if any two opposing bases are closer then `s-w`

[Notes]

- I think the best way is the per pixel
- it is most close to the solution you want
- the render can be a bit slower but you need to change it only if any base is conquered