# Unordered cloud point of polygon contour to polygon

Tags: python, geometry, 2d, polygon, computational-geometry

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I have contours of irregular polygons as unordered datapoints (like on the figure here: https://s16.postimg.org/pum4m0pn9/figure_4.png), and I am trying to order them (ie. to create a polygon).

[image]

I cannot use the convex hull envelope because of the non convex shape of the polygon. I cannot ase a minimum distance criterion because some points of other parts of the contour lie closer (example: point A has to be joined with B, but is closer to C). I cannot use a clockwise ordering because of the irregular shape of the contour.

Do anyone knos a way to implement (preferentially in Python) an algorithm that would reorder the datapoints from a starting point?

Comment: The thing is that the order in which you go through your points can define different polygons so that there is no unique solution in general.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `shapely` module for python? It features a lot of functions for polygons and the like. Maybe you can find your needs already implemented there... https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely

Comment: Your problem is similar to the "travelling salesman problem".  I had solved this problem with "simulated annealing" many years ago. It should be pretty straight forward to implement it.

Comment: look here [finding holes in 2D point set](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214) for some ideas on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

look here [finding holes in 2D point set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214) for some ideas on how to solve this

1. I would create point density map (similar to above linked answer)
2. create list of all lines

   - so add to it all possible combination of lines (between close points)
   - not intersecting empty area in map
3. remove all intersecting lines
4. apply closed loop / connectivity analysis on the lines
5. then handle the rest of unused points

   - by splitting nearest line by them ...
   - [image: map example]
   - depending on you map grid size and point density you may need to blend/smooth the map to cover gaps
   - if grid size is too big then you can miss details like on the image between points A,C
   - if it is too small then significant gaps may occur near low density areas

But as said this has more then one solution so you need to tweak this a bit to make the wanted output perhaps some User input for shaking the solution a bit until wanted solution found...

[notes]

you can handle this as more covex polygons ...

- add line only if winding rule met
- stop when no more lines found
- start again with unused points
- and in the end try to connect found non closed polygons ...