# How to create a polygon out of the outer cells of a contiguous patch of cells

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry

I have below a contiguous patch of cells plotted in Matlab.
[image]

The outer cells of the red patch have to be determined and then a polygon joining the centers of these cells will give me a polygon. How do i compute the outer cells of the contiguous patch?

I have an array of integers whose elements denote the cell in the red patch, for example,

```
a=[1;64;23;456;345];
```

Each element , say 64 corresponds to a cell in the image, and it is the cell belonging to the red patch.

The motivation to solve the problem is to deal with a polygon with minimal number of edges rather than so many cells. it slows down computation. Convex hull is not good enough. I don't want the resulting polygon to overlap with the brown area at all.

What i am suggesting is the case on the left in image below but it seems ugly. So a better way would be as in right to just skip the cells only sharing a single point with the outer brown area. I would like my outer cells to then be only those that share more than just a single point with the outer brown area.

But we want to avoid large number of edges in the resultant polygon!

[image]

Comment: similar to this [Outline circumference polygon extraction from geometry constructed from equal squares](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33473452/2521214) and [Determine Minimum Number of Line Segments to Solve a Maze](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30908390/2521214)

Comment: thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer by @rahnema1 is really cool, I think the OP is asking more how to extract the set of edges according to the described rules.

Here is my approach identifying all the 10 patterns of 2x2 pixels that contain edges. Assuming the matrix `A` has the image with `1`s and `0`s (`A = zeros(ny, nx); A(a) = 1`):

```
% we identify patterns with edges over 2x2 patches, describing with
% the first 4 binary values what pixels are set, and with the next 2
% the edge with 2 indices over the 2x2 patch
patterns = [
 0,1,0,1,  3,4 % vertical edge at rhe right 
 1,0,1,0,  1,2 % vertical edge at the left
 0,0,1,1,  2,4 % horizontal edge at the bottom
 1,1,0,0,  1,3 % horizontal edge at the top
 1,0,0,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge
 0,1,1,0,  2,3 % diagonal edge
 1,0,1,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
 1,1,0,1,  1,4 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
 1,1,1,0,  2,3 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
 0,1,1,1,  2,3 % diagonal edge, extra pixel set
];

% 2x2 patches (matrix form)
P00 = A(1:end-1,1:end-1);
P10 = A(2:end,1:end-1);
P01 = A(1:end-1,2:end);
P11 = A(2:end,2:end);

% edge unique identifier using powers of 2
id = @(p00,p01,p10,p11) 1*p00 + 2*p10 + 4*p01 + 8*p11;
P = id(P00,P01,P10,P11); % vectorized pattern identification

% edges
e0 = []; % from (i,j)
e1 = []; % to (i,j)
for i = 1:size(patterns, 1) % small loop over the 10 patterns
  p = patterns(i, :);
  E = (P == id(p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4))); % pattern search, vectorized
  [c,r] = ind2sub(size(E), find(E));
  [c0,r0] = ind2sub([2,2], p(5));
  [c1,r1] = ind2sub([2,2], p(6));
  e0 = [e0; c+c0, r+r0];
  e1 = [e1; c+c1, r+r1];
end
```

And here the result applying it to your image (I used GIMP for capture, resize and filter, so maybe the image is not *exactly* the same):

```
X = [e0(:,2) e1(:,2)];
Y = size(A,1) - [e0(:,1) e1(:,1)];
plot(X', Y', '.-')
```

[image: Resulting set of edges]

I am assuming that obtaining an ordered sequence of edges describing the polygon (or polygons) is not the main problem here once you have the aforementioned set.

Comment: This is the solution i was looking for. But i was wondering how to obtain a nx2 matrix storing the vertices of the polygon in clockwise or counterclockwise manner starting from any vertex?

Comment: I tired:- `X=X'; Y=Y'; new_poly=[X(1,:)',Y(1,:)'];line(new_poly(:,1), new_poly(:,2));` This did not work.

Comment: What is the name of this method you used involving 2x2 patches and powers of 2? Could you point me to some source to understand this in more detail?

Comment: I guess this is an example of a "marching squares" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I first processed the sample image from your question to create a logical mask (you already have an example of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44398320/52738)).

Once you have this mask, there is a really easy way to generate the polygon you want using the [`bwtraceboundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html) function from the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html). This will give you a set of pixel indices in order around the perimeter of your masked region:

```
[r, c] = find(mask, 1);
coords = bwtraceboundary(mask, [r c], 'N');
```

And we can visualize it like so:

```
imagesc(mask);
colormap([0.9 0.9 0.9; 0.6 0.6 0.6]);
axis equal
set(gca, 'XLim', [0.5 0.5+size(mask, 2)], 'YLim', [0.5 0.5+size(mask, 1)]);
hold on;
plot(coords(:, 2), coords(:, 1), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
plot(coords(1, 2), coords(1, 1), 'go', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

The coordinates for the red line are ordered starting from the green circle and moving clockwise around the perimeter pixels of the masked region.

If you would prefer to generate a boundary outline that follows along the perimeter pixel *edges* of the region instead of the perimeter pixel *centers*, you can use the solution from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230034/52738) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45203862/52738). This will yield the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Image Processing toolbox You can apply `dilation` on the image and than  apply `and operator` between result of dilation and the original image.

[image][image]

```
A = imread('bnhfm.png');
B = A & imdilate(~A, true(3));
imshow(B);
imwrite(B, 'result.png');
```

Comment: Very cool trick! How did you convert the red-brown image to black and white? Can it be done thru matlab programatically?

Comment: @user_1_1_1 I used an image editing software to do it, However I believe it can be done thru matlab with some effort . It my be subject to a new question.