# Finding the nearest path in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, knn

I am working on a project with big data and I have some trouble to find the nearest path (or cluster) in the data. I'm trying to find the nearest path to the center where a few data can be seen on the excel scatter pilot. I'm just trying to find the distance from the center where the data shows. Another example with the data is heatmap. Area with the no data can be seen on the heatmap as dark blue color.
I try to use Reverse K-nearest neighbour algorithm and I also try to do it with RNN-DBSCAN and I couldn't achieve it. Can anyone know how to find that diagonal shape in the center where no data shown?

[[image: Scatter Pilot on Excel]

[image: Heatmap Examples]

Thank you for the help.

An example of the shape that I want to find can be seen below. Some of the dots inside the red line will probably be outliers. I want to find the position of the edges on the red line.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: I just want to find the diagonal shape in the center where no data visible.

Comment: Can you mark it in one of your plots?

Comment: I just uploaded a new picture that I want to find.

Comment: maybe this helps you get on the right track https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816562/finding-holes-in-2d-point-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you for the help. I need some exact lines and edges so image processing might cause some problem in my project.