# Detecting holes in a dirty triangle mesh (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Detecting holes in a triangle mesh should be easy: Collect the edges that have only one adjacent triangle (degree-1 edges) and construct closed polylines from it. However, the mesh has been made from a scanned point cloud and it has bubbles. Thus the set of degree-1 edges does not completely describe the hole. The image below shows

- Degree-1 edges in red
- Degree-2 edges in black
- Degree-3 edges in purple

I try already to find a paths to close the polylines. But that's not really a robust solution. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you could adapt this [Finding holes in 2d point sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214) to 3D and use the map to decide if your edge is really near hole or not ...